# Cycles - How to transfer information from a shader to another non-destructively ? (no baking)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, shaders, mathematics

How can we **non-destructively** (witouth baking anything into vertex color nor bitmap) transfer information from one shader to another within cycles ?

Here's an example :

**Here is a simple proximity shader on my plane.[image]** and below are a bunch of instanced trees.
I'd like to use the black and white information from my plane to drive transparency on from my instanced trees location, how am i supposed to do that, **non destructively** (no baking)

[image]

Comment: If you are using particles to create the trees you could always set the objects to have a collision and to kill the particles

Comment: Hello, I have 2 comments : Using a Vector Math node set to Length will do the same as using Distance to 0,0,0. And : Why not using dynamic paint with vertex groups in this particular case ?

Comment: Girgious, the question is not about the proximity shader, dynamic paint solution may work with some vertex weight or colors in this case. the point of the question is how it's possible to transfer information from one shader to another. it could be anything, ambient occlusion, procedural textures etc...